# Change segue endpoint using Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue

**How do you change the endpoint of an existing segue using storyboard?**

Obviously I can delete and re-create the segue but this adds a potential for "operator error". Eg if I accidentally mistype the segue's identifier, the code will later crash.

Storyboard doesn't seem to offer this really simple functionality. Can't drag the segue to somewhere else, can't see any config items that refer to its endpoint. Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can't change endpoints of existing segue. You have to create new one. You can't drag and drop endpoint to some viewcontroller to other.

And there is no need of it also.

For example, let's assume scenario like : You have one view controller called A, and you have given segue from A to another Viewcontroller B and segue name is `segueToB`. Now you have another viewcontroller say C and now you want to give segue from A to this C then make `Another segue`. no need to delete `segueToB`. Create `segueToC` which points A to C. Now when you want to go from A to B then perform `segueToB` segue. When you want to go from A to C then perform `segueToC` segue. Likewise you can make multiple segue. There is no need to change endpoint or delete segue and change identifier everytime.